# Updating a table column using coredata

Tags: iphone, core-data

I have a table called CCAccount having 8 fileds.When i register i enter only 3 fields and other fields will be empty.When i click addPasscode button i need to enter passcode to CCAccount table having ccid=myccid.how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `NSPredicate`, see this [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/Articles/pUsing.html) to know how to use it.